# Powershell running a command from variable

Tags: powershell, command-line

I am trying to run a command that I have stored as a string in a variable, however when I try to run it with "Invoke-Command" I am told it needs to be "ScriptBlock" and not a string.
The command is:

```
ASIMPORT.EXE -rexactdb-01 -DTEST001 -u -~ I -URL X:\test.xml -Tglentries -OPT18 –Oauto
```

I am trying to run it as:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $command
```

Tried with and without "ScriptBlock", always get the same error. Googling it, I honestly do not understand how should I approach the solution, so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your variable as a scriptblock.

Like that:

```
$ScriptBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create("get-process")

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `Invoke-Command`, you need [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6):

```
$command = 'svn help patch'
Invoke-expression $command
```

See cmdlet description:

> The Invoke-Expression cmdlet evaluates or runs a specified string as a
>   command and returns the results of the expression or command. Without
>   Invoke-Expression, a string submitted at the command line would be
>   returned (echoed) unchanged.

Comment: This is the most useful answer, since Invoke-Command does not allow any results to be returned from the command.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {&$command}
```